# Is there a way to calculate the Ka/Ks value in R/unix?

Tags: r, snp, bash

I am investigating the rate of synonymous non synonymous substitutions and would like to find the Ka/Ks value also known as dn and ds between multiple alleles? I want to investigate multiple alleles because I am examining the MHC region which is highly polymorphic. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also used the [seqinr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seqinr/index.html) package for [Ka/Ks](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seqinr/versions/4.2-8/topics/kaks)

Answer (score 1):

A while back, I used [`PAML`](http://abacus.gene.ucl.ac.uk/software/paml.html) for this purpose for a phylogenetics project. It has Windows and macOS executables but for *nix, you will need to compile it from source code.